# replace hard links with copies

Tags: linux, hardlink

I have a file which has other hard links. I want to let it become independent.

I know it can be done like this:

```
mv myfile temp
cp -a temp myfile
```

Is there any single command which does not require a temporary file to perform the operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a bit of research on this. Basically, the answer is no, because of the lack of support from operating system. For detail see similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66815/breaking-a-hard-link-in-place/148717#148717)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861400/rename-from-a-file-descriptor/25154505#25154505)